# Azure Active Directory and PowerShell: Add groups as owners and Az Support for owner assignments

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I am currently trying to automate the creation of groups via PowerShell scripts. Two experiences I made are

1) The Az module is rather limited and does not cover the whole set of commands the AzureAD module provides. E.g. I want to add an owner to a group. How can I do that? And is there a plan to transfer all functionality to Az?

2) Is it possible to add groups as owners to a group? I would like to avoid to add single users.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) The Az module is rather limited and does not cover the whole set of
>   commands the AzureAD module provides. E.g. I want to add an owner to a
>   group. How can I do that? And is there a plan to transfer all
>   functionality to Az?

For the plan to provide the feature to add an owner to a group, you could post this idea on User Voice for further information.

Currently, a workaround is that you could choose to connect a session using an existing token associated with the active azure context.

Here is an example to connect to Azure AD module with your Az context. Then use Azure AD cmd `Add-AzureADGroupOwner` in your script.

```
# login
Connect-AzAccount -tenant {tenant id}
# perform other Azure operations...

$currentAzureContext = Get-AzContext
$tenantId = $currentAzureContext.Tenant.Id
$accountId = $currentAzureContext.Account.Id
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $tenantId -AccountId $accountId
Add-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId "62438306-7c37-4638-a72d-0ee8d9217680" -RefObjectId "0a1068c0-dbb6-4537-9db3-b48f3e31dd76"
```

> 2) Is it possible to add groups as owners to a group? I would like to
>   avoid to add single users.

It's not supported to add groups as owners to a group. We can only get the member lists and loop them to add the members as the owner of a group.

```
$members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId {object id of group}

Foreach($member in $members){
    Add-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId {object id of the target group} -RefObjectId $member.ObjectId
}
```

Please note that if a member is a another group, the cmd cannot add it as the owner.

Answer (score 1):

1) I do not believe there is a plan to move all azure ad functionality to az, they are actively developing the azureAD for graph module. if you look at other Modules, like exchange, teams, sharepoint, they each have their own modules to manage the service. the az module is meant more for managing azure resources. not specifically azure ad. although there is a some basic azure ad functionality.

2) groups can't be owners in azure ad. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-accessmanagement-managing-group-owners
you don't have a choice with group owners. they have to be single users or service principals.

> Group owners can be users or service principals

The best you can do is build your own automation scripts to add remove group owners based on your requirements.